# Kinetis KEA: Frequency of LED toggling for the timer interrupt generated

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller, nxp-microcontroller

I am using a Kinetis KEA64 microcontroller from NXP.

The actual frequency of clock is 20 MHz, and a timer interrupt is generated at every 2.5ms. I have an interrupt handler that toggles an LED when this timer interrupt is generated. LED is toggling on this timer interrupt but i dont know exactly the frequency of LED. Does my LED toggles at 5kHz? Is it correct?

```
void interrupt_application_timer_FTM0()
{
    SIM_SCGC |= SIM_SCGC_FTM0_MASK; /* Enable Clock for FTM0 */         
    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_PS(7);    /* Select Preescaler in this case 128. 20 Mhz /128 =156.25 Khz. */ 
                                    /* Counter increase by one every 6.4 us */      
        /* Enable Channle 0*/
    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_CHIE_MASK; /* Enable channel 0 interrupt */
    FTM0_C0SC |= FTM_CnSC_MSA_MASK;  /* Channel as Output compare mode */           
        /*Select interrupt frequency*/
    FTM0_C0V = FTM_CnV_VAL(391) ;       /* Interrupt every 2.5ms */ 

    FTM0_SC |= FTM_SC_CLKS(1); /*FTM0 use system clock*/

        /* Set the ICPR and ISER registers accordingly */
    NVIC_ICPR |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
    NVIC_ISER |= 1 << ((INT_FTM0-16)%32);
}
```

Here is my interrupt handler

```
void FTM0_IRQHandler()
  {     
    if (1==((FTM0_C0SC & FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK)>>FTM_CnSC_CHF_SHIFT) )  /* If the CHF of the channel is equal to 0 */
    {
        (void)FTM0_C0SC;                            /* Read to clear flag */
        FTM0_C0SC ^= FTM_CnSC_CHF_MASK;             /* Clear flag */
        FTM0_C0V = FTM0_C0V + 391 ; /* Refresh interrupt period */

        if (LED_counter>=50){
            /* Toggle LED */
            /* Reset counter */
            LED0_TOGGLE;
            LED_counter = 0;
        }
        LED_counter++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: 5ms is 200Hz, which will just make the LED look dim. You need to get down to about 10Hz before you can actually see the LED turning off and on.

Comment: I can see the LED turn on and off. But donot know the frequency with which it is blinking

Comment: Doesn't look like a SO question at the first sight.

Comment: I was taking your word for it that the interrupt is occurring every 2.5 msec. If you can see the LED blinking, then either the interrupt is running much slower than 2.5 msec, or the code isn't toggling the LED on every interrupt.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  Nobody can answer your question without a look at your interrupt handler.

Comment: For problems like that a scope helps a lot.

Comment: You haven't mentioned which MCU you are using, so how do you expect anyone to be able to answer this? "NXP" can literally mean anything nowadays, from Motorola 6800 to Cortex A.

Comment: I am using kinetis KEA64 microcontroller

Comment: I concluded it is running at frequency of 5KHz because. The clock runs at 20MHz. And an interrupt is generated at every 2.5ms which means interrupt is generated at 400Hz. Now 20MHz divided by 400 Hz give 5Khz. Is it right??

Comment: @j.aug : Eh!?  If the LED is toggled at 400Hz, then the frequency is 400 / 2 - 200Hz.  The counter reload value required would be 20e6/400 = 5000 (assuming no prescaler in the timer clock).  Your code has 391 which would be over 51KHz.  In either case you have said you can _see_ the LED toggling - if that is the case then something else is happening.  You have not shown the interrupt handler itself or specified the exact part you are using so it is hard to advise.

Comment: You are also probably asking the wrong question - asking what frequency it is running at.  It would probably be simpler to specify what frequency you _want_ it to toggle at, and ask how to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use scope for frequency measuring
2. In the MCU, you can enable bus clock to one pin (Busclockout), enable that and check the bus clock so that you can confirm your calculations
3. Then use scope at LED to confirm your frequency